# Country Specific google place autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

I am following http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/ this tutorial to get google place autocomplete in my app,
Now that it is working fine but I need to keep the place suggestion country specific, I have tried giving country like india , china but it is not showing any result.
Could you please help me out and tell where should I need to change the code to get it done.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: The method in that tutorial is old json parsing. If you use the autocomplete for android. You can refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete). Also you can get the demo from [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete). I tried and it worked fine. For country specific, you can use A LatLngBounds object, restricting the results to a specific area specified by latitude and longitude bounds.

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation for Places API

> To get a list of predicted place names and/or addresses, call
> GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(), passing the following
> parameters:
>
> Required: A query string containing the text typed by the user.
>
> Required: A **LatLngBounds** object, restricting the results to a specific
> area specified by latitude and longitude bounds.

When making request

> You can specify bounds for India.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to make it general like wherever the user is in,his country bound will be set dynamically.

Comment: @hiccup Could you able to find bounds dynamically as per country?

Answer (score 0):

**This can serve you**

```
    String apiKey = getString(R.string.places_api_key);
        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);
            PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(PlaceAutocompleteActivity.this, "-----initialize-----", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        // PlaceFields
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));

        // autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(MapsActivity.this);

        try {

            autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                    displayLocation(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude,place.getName());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getName: " + place.getName() + " getLatLng: "+ place.getLatLng(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//                    Intent i = Intent(this, idnow.se MainActivity.class);
//                    i.putExtra("getLatLng",place.getLatLng());
//                    startActivity(i);
//                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(PlaceAutocompleteActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

---

> // PlaceFields - HERE

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
```

https://github.com/EddyEU/GooglePlaceAutocomplete